# gcsfuse terminating itself on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, fuse, gcsfuse

I have gcsfuse in a deployment on GKE, it was working fine and without any changes in the config it started failing since yesterday.

```
Received signal 15; terminating.
```

I have it deployed in 2 different clusters, first I thought it was related to the kubernetes version because I started to see the issue when upgraded to *1.17.14-gke.1200*, but in the other cluster I still have *1.17.14-gke.400* and both have same issue.

Comment: Signal 15 is SIGTERM. Could you go to stackdriver and checkout the delete log for your pod? I may be related to the garbage collector in the Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem, I was using the command as follows `gcsfuse -o nonempty --implicit-dirs...`, when I removed the `-o nonempty` flag it started working.

The strange thing is that it was working just fine until 2 days ago, suddenly that stopped working.

I decided to try without that after reading this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#mount8-and-fstab-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

The option “nonempty” is not supported when the library fusermount3 is available, as stated in comment [[1]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/424#issuecomment-725060825) of the issue #424 [[2]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/424), .

> The options used by fusermount and fusermount3 are different. Option
> nonempty is supported by fusermount, but not fusermount3. So, when the
> OS has fusermount3 installed and nonempty used, the mounting will
> fail. Simple fix: Remove nonempty when upgrading gcsfuse to v0.31 or
> later.

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/424#issuecomment-725060825

[2] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/424